# 403 http error in backed of my Yii2 project on host

Tags: php, yii2

I used Yii2 framework with advanced template. when i run my project on lampp, everything is fine, but when i copied and test on my host, backend of my project it get 403 http error. everythong looks fine and my files perimission is 0757, where did I go wrong?

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```